# Function Related to the Gamma Function

Tags: gamma-function

I know that 
$$
\Gamma(z) = \int_0^{\infty} x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx 
$$
is the Gamma function, but what about 
$$
\int_a^{\infty} x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx 
$$
for some $a > 0$? Does this function have a special name? I figure I'm okay with writing a function to evaluate this when $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ because if we take the change of variables $y = x-a$, then 
\begin{align*}
\int_a^{\infty} x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx &= \int_0^{\infty}(y+a)^{z-1}e^{-(y+a)}dy \\
&= e^{-a} \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{z-1}{z-1 \choose k}y^ka^{z-1-k} e^{-y}dy \\
&= e^{-a} \sum_{k=0}^{z-1} {z-1 \choose k} a^{z-1-k} \int_0^{\infty} y^k e^{-y}dy \\
&= e^{-a} \sum_{k=0}^{z-1} {z-1 \choose k} a^{z-1-k} \Gamma(k+1), 
\end{align*}
but this isn't enough for me because I am interested in $z \overset{\text{set}}{=} 3/2$ and considering it as a function of $a$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: The particular thing you need is the error function for $z=3/2$, which is related to the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: oh I've heard of those. Thanks guys. Also related to the cumulative distribution function of a gamma random variable.